# How to prevent Idea Intellij to change MODULE_DIR in IML files?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using Intellij Ultimate 2020.2, in a multi-module Maven project, my IML files use the MODULE_PATH variable, like this:

```
<component ...>
  <option name="directories">
    <list>
      <option value="$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" />
```

But when I refresh (switch branch, build, etc.) Intellij replaces MODULE_DIR by the reel path, for example:

```
<component ...>
  <option name="directories">
    <list>
      <option value="C:/somepath/myproject/mywebapp/src/main/java" />
```

Is there a way to prevent Intellij to change the content?

Comment: What do you have in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Path Variables?

Comment: I do only have KOTLIN_BUNDLED and MAVEN_REPOSITORY